# Android Notification on Wear device. `localOnly` flag

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I have a few notifications running on my app built with `NotificationCompat`

Depending on the type, they show background bitmaps, or list of text, also most of them have 1 or 2 actions using the code:

```
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_notification, text, pendingIntent)
```

some of those actions makes sense for a watch (for example: "like" or "reply") and some doesn't (for example: "view album").

I thought I could use the `setLocalOnly(boolean)` method for it, but I found out that it is applied to the whole notification, not just to individual actions.

I've also been checking on `NotificationCompat.Action` and `NotificationCompat.Action.WearableExtender` but couldn't find anything that would be relevant.

---

So the question:

is there a way to make the notification show on the watch, but only with some of the actions but not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) in the paragraph "Specify wearable-only actions".

Comment: super, exactly what I needed. Sometimes I'm too keen to read the docs and forget the training material.

Comment: Remember to accept the replies on stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: I did, but StackoverFlow told me to wait 7 mins

Comment: I already marked as correct, but I have a valid follow up question that I couldn't see on those training material. What if none of the actions are good for wearable, and I want to show just the notification without any action?

Comment: I don't know. Never tried this case. Maybe you can build a null action in some way.